# powerbi-client - getting the list of the available aggregations for a data field

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to create a custom UI for applying aggregations for the Data Fields assigned to the visuals. [Following the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/targets) I know about the different targets.

I found the [list of the accepted values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/targets#aggregation-functions) for the `IColumnAggrTarget['aggregationFunction']`

However, the problem is to know **which** of them can be applied. And **if** a particular Data Field can be aggregated at all.

`IVisualDataRole` [provides kind property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-models/ivisualdatarole#powerbi-models-ivisualdatarole-kind), but that's not enough to determine if aggregation can be applied.

For example, if you take a look at the text field used in the Pivot Table - values, you'll see in the Power BI, that only a certain subset of aggregations can be applied. What is interesting 'Do not summarize' is not one of them.

[image]

In addition, if you programmatically apply the wrong aggregation, the related visual land in the broken "fix me" state.

[image]

Is there any way to be able to get that list programmatically?